# Нужна помощь по JS

Tags: javascript

нужна помощь, у меня есть рулетка которая на главной странице ( и кнопка и рулетка ), хотелось бы сделать чтоб сначала показывалась кнопка, после ее нажатие открывалась та самая рулетка, заранее спасибо

Comment: Положи код в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Размести разметку твоей рулетки внутри div-элемента с css-классом, который скрывает этот элемент. В обработчике события нажатия кнопки удали с элемента css-класс.
Например:

```html
<style>
.roulette-container{
display: none;
}
</style>
<button onclick="showRoulette();">
Отобразить
</button>
<div class="roulette-container" id="rCont">
   Рулетка
</div>
<script>
function showRoulette(){
let el = document.getElementById("rCont");
el.classList.remove("roulette-container");
}
</script>
```